# Cannot get custom variable value from Azure DevOps Release

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops

In an Azure DevOps Release, I want to create a new variable inside a PowerShell task :

```
Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=MYVAR;]myValue 1")
Write-host $env:MYVAR
Write-host $MYVAR

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MYVAR;]myValue 2"
Write-Host "$env:MYVAR"
Write-host $MYVAR
```

I was expecting the result to be:

```
myValue 1
myValue 1
myValue 2
myValue 2
```

But I got 4 empty values. I didn' find any clue in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=vsts&tabs=powershell).

Am I missing something?

Comment: i dont think it will exist in the same step. you can access that in subsequent steps though

Comment: What a shame, so weird it's only available outside the current task :( Thanks for your quick answer. Please create proper one and I will accept it.

Comment: well, this kinda makes sense. you can use powershell directly to store this variable in this step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way Azure Devops works, this variable will only be available in subsequent steps.